# How to find out if a class is an instance of a generic interface in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

So is it possible to get an instance of `Property<T>` is `Property` and, not knowing its generic `T` type parameter, to call its methods?

```
private interface Property<T> 
{
    T Value { get;}
    void DestroyEarth();
}

class MyProperty : Property<int>
{
    public int Value{ get { return 1 }; }
    public void  DestroyEarth() { }
}
```

So I am wondering if I can call `DestroyEarth()` on MyProperty instances received by a method like

```
void PropertyCaller(Property p){p.DestroyEarth();}
```

(Note: we do not define or have simple `Property` class or interface nowhere )

Comment: Could you post some code as an example of what you need?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "yes", but an illustration of `Property<T>`, `Property`, and the relationship between them would be useful. Otherwise "yes" will probably have to suffice. Also: whether the methods are coming from `Property` or `Property<T>` would help!

Comment: please post an example of your code so your question becomes clearer...
I can't figure out what you want to do exactly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

with the question edit, I would say: declare a non-generic interface and move the methods that don't relate to `T`, for example:

```
interface IProperty {
    object Value { get;}
    void DestroyEarth();
}
interface IProperty<T> : IProperty {
    new T Value { get;}
}

class MyProperty : IProperty<int>
{
    object IProperty.Value { get { return Value; } }
    public int Value{get {return 1;} }
    public void  DestroyEarth(){}
}
```

and just code against `IProperty` when you don't know the `T`.

(a different answer, from before you posted code, is in the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2e7007ba-1244-4b93-85ca-cf66759f5d80/view-source), for reference)

Then you have:

```
void PropertyCaller(IProperty p) { p.DestroyEarth(); }
```

Of course, you could also just let the compiler figure out the `T`:

```
void PropertyCaller<T>(IProperty<T> p) { p.DestroyEarth(); }
```

Comment: +1 "Of course, you could also just let the compiler figure out the T:"  Short, sweet, and doesn't require OP to redefine anything else.

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking for is an automatic conversion between `Property<T>` types to `Property<object>` (i guess) in cases where you don't know the T and still want to call that instance in some way. This can't be done for various reasons (research "covariance/contravariance" in generic types for some insight on the problem space).

I recommend doing this conversion yourself and implement an `IProperty` (non generic - see Marc's answer) interface on top of your `Property<T>` class that has the same signature but with T written as object. Then implement by hand the call re-directions to the T methods with casts when needed.

Answer (score -1):

Your `Property` class should has some implementation regardless to `T`, and `Property<T>` derives from `Property`, with more implementation related to `T`.